# Laravel. How to handle sort_order column shift

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I have such a table, and `SomeModel`, that represents it

```
| id              | name             | sort_order       |
| --------------- | ---------------- | ---------------- |
| 1               | A                | 1                |
| 2               | B                | 2                |
| 3               | C                | 3                |
| 4               | D                | 8                |
```

I'm implementing an API for this table. How to handle properly `sort_order` column shift during inserting the same values.

*For example:*

I want to save such an object:

```
{
    "name": "B2",
    "sort_order": 2
}
```

and receive such a table:

```
| id              | name             | sort_order       |
| --------------- | ---------------- | ---------------- |
| 1               | A                | 1                |
| 5               | B2               | 2                |
| 2               | B                | 3                | <--- initially was 2
| 3               | C                | 4                | <--- initially was 3
| 4               | D                | 8                |
```

How to implement it?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with that example object? That's invalid json with duplicate key's like that.

Comment: `object` not clear, please clear what you have actually require?

Comment: @btl @bharat No matter what. php array, php object, whatever. I have the problem NOT with the format, but with SHIFTING other models' `sort_order`. And about "invalid json with duplicate key's". Sorry. Silly copy-paste error.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
use App\SomeModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function insert_data(Request $request){  
    SomeModel::where("sort_order", ">=", $request->sort_order)->increment("sort_order");
    SomeModel::create($request->all());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have some model you can do this:

In your `AppServiceProvider`

```
Event::listen("eloquent.inserting: ".SomeModel::class, function (SomeModel $model) {
      SomeModel::where("sort_order", ">=", $model->sort_order)
             ->update([ "sort_order" => \DB::raw("sort_order+1") ])
});
```

The idea is to update all other models with a sort order higher or equal to the one you're inserting and increment it by one. You might want to do something similar with the deleting event to fill in the gaps and perhaps the updating event to swap sort orders.

You can (and should) dig deeper into the event system for models by reading the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events)

Of course you could always set the sort_order column as unique and create a DB trigger to keep the sort orders in check for you which is probably better since this is a data integrity concern.